# react-admin selectArrayInput without choices

Tags: react-admin

We need an **input field** to enter **multiple values**. In our case tags. The user should be able to enter new tags which are not in `choices` property.

In admin-on-rest there was very nice . It was exactly what we needed.

[image: multi value input]

Unfortunately in ***react-admin*** I wasn't able to find such feature and it is essential for us to move from admin-on-rest to react-admin.

**SelectArrayInput**, which is available works only with predefined choices.

Is there an alternative solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We removed it from react-admin because the `AutocompleteField` was removed from material-ui. You'll have to implement your own input for that, using https://github.com/TeamWertarbyte/material-ui-chip-input which recently merged a pull request allowing autocompletion using `react-autosuggest` or `downshift` (see https://github.com/TeamWertarbyte/material-ui-chip-input/pull/219)

Comment: Thanks. I've already implemented a solution with two fields: 1 field: to select an autocompleted tag from a list (thanks for implementing this feature in react-admin 2.3.0). And the 2 field: to add new values.